# Can you cap J. Roget Champagne Bottles with bottle caps?

Tags: bottling, capping, caps

I have capped several different champagne bottles with 29mm bottle caps, but the 29mm caps seem to fit too loosely on a case of J. Roget Champagne bottles I just picked up.

I was having troubles getting the standard 26mm caps to go on them also.  Are they un-cappable?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience you need to just get some champagne corks and wire ties. This is harder to do without the aid of a corker but the caps won't keep the air out as well as any baddies that will get in to your bottles.